# Is the location that published calendars use to calculate the seasons one specific location on the earth?

Tags: star-gazing

All the calendars in my house say the fall equinox is Tuesday the 23rd. All the astronomical programs and astronomical sources say it is it is Monday the 22nd in Ohio. Since the time given is 10:29 p.m. EDT all of the US starts fall on Monday. I’m guessing the calendars use Greenwich Time. This same discussion also applies to when calendars show the full moon dates.

I know this isn't exactly an astonomy question, but I thought this site was the closest I could get.

Answer (score 1):

Astronomical events such as the solstices and equinoxes occur at a specific instance in time on a specific day, often given in [Universal Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Time).

For example, this winter's solstice occurs on 21 Dec 2014 at 23:03 Universal Time. Since most of Europe is an hour ahead, this may occur on 22 Dec 2014 at 00:03 (and subsequent hours) given in local time based on the [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone). So British and American calendars will show the solstice occurring on 21 Dec, and in countries east of [Greenwich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Observatory,_Greenwich) on 22 Dec.